# Quasar Vue - How to call a method from dynamic loaded content from database

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I have made a simple app using Quasar Framework - I load content from the database, and want to call a method on the component that opens a dialog. But I don't know how to do that, nothing happens.. What to do?

The button is rendered, but nothing happens when i click it.

Show video ( dynamic data loaded from the database ):

```
<button @click='showVideo()'>frea</button>
```

The showVideo() method exists on the component that loads and shows the button.

Data from VueX, using actions and getters

Action:

```
return axiosInstance.get('/program/' + id).then(res => {
  commit(Mutation.SET_PROGRAM, res.data)
})
```

Component:

created:

```
this[ProgramAction.FETCH_PROGRAM](this.$route.params.id)
```

computed:

```
...mapGetters('program', ['program'])
```

Comment: please add details about how you're getting that data

Comment: VueX action:
return axiosInstance.get('/program/' + id).then(res => {
      commit(Mutation.SET_PROGRAM, res.data)
    })
Component:
this[ProgramAction.FETCH_PROGRAM](this.$route.params.id)
computed:
...mapGetters('program', ['program'])

Comment: this is hard to read, please edit your question with that details and give the scenario on how are you proceeding